# Array type char[] is not assignable

Tags: c, arrays, string, assignment-operator

Well here is my first post. I've been trying to do this choice choosing thing and I want the user to choose only numbers instead of typing them down (easier) but when I want the numbers to equal a string, it says "array type `char[30]` is not assignable". Even if at the back I put semi-colon or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int choice1;
  char word[30];

  printf("You have three choice.\n");
  printf("[1] Jump [2] Run [3] Dance\n");
  scanf("%d",&choice1);
  if (choice1 == 1)
  {
    word = "Jump" //Error #1
  }
  else if (choice1 == 2)
  {
    word = "Eat" //Error #2
  }
  else if (choice1 == 3)
  {
    word = "Sleep"; //Error #3
  }

  printf("You will now be %sing",word);

}
```

Comment: if you do want to assign to `word` without `strcpy` you can make `word` typed like `const char *word`.

Comment: Surprisingly, you get the error because array type char[] is not assignable. In C, you can't assign strings like you do, because there is no built-in string type, just raw character arrays. Anyway, this is such a FAQ... someone please find a duplicate.

Comment: The accepted answer in the "duplicate" is not an answer (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer?rq=1), just a link to a horrible FAQ.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can't *assign* to an array, only *copy* to it.

Use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) instead, like

```
strcpy(word, "Jump");
```

Comment: suggesting some 3rd party library function like strcpy without identifying where/what external library needs to be downloaded and installed to access it is the opposite of future-proof.

Comment: @DavidBandel `strcpy` is a standard C function. It's most definitely not "3rd party".

Comment: add this line to use strcpy #include<string.h>

Answer (score 21):

**TL;DR** answer : An array *name* is **not** a modifiable lvalue. So, you cannot use the assignment operator (`=`) on that.

To copy the content into the array, you need to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) from `string.h` (`char` array) or [`memcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) in general.

---

Now, to elaborate the *actual reason* behind the error message, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16, `Assignment operators`

> assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and then, quoting chapter §6.3.2.1 from the same standard,

> A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that does not have array type, [....]

So, an array name is not a *modifiable lvalue* hence, you cannot *assign* anything to it. This is the reason behind the error message.

Comment: But I wonder why the C spec is defined this way? Seems reasonable to want to assign from one array to another...

Comment: @nielsbot I can think of two related reasons - 1) there's no operator overloading in C 2) array names, decay to the pointer to the first element in most of the cases (including when used as operand of the assignment operator) - so there's no direct way to copy the contents. At most, the address can be used - but that's not the use case we're looking for here.

Answer (score 14):

The `=` operator cannot be used to copy the *contents* of one array to the other; you must use a library function like `strcpy` or `strcat` for strings, `memcpy` for non-strings (or assign array elements individually).

This is a consequence of how C treats array *expressions*.  An array expression is defined by the language standard to be a *non-modifiable lvalue*; it's an lvalue because it refers to an object in memory, but it may not be the target of an assignment.

The array subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`; that is, given the array *address* `a`, offset `i` elements from that address and dereference the result.  Since the array expression `a` is treated as a pointer, most people think `a` variable *stores* a pointer to the first element of the array, but it doesn't.  All that gets stored are the array elements themselves.

Instead, whenever the compiler sees an array expression in a statement, it *converts* that expression from type "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression becomes the address of the first element of the array (unless the expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration).

And this is why an array expression like `word` cannot be the target of an assignment; there's nothing to assign *to*.  There's no object `word` that exists independently of `word[0]`, `word[1]`, etc.

When you write

```
word = "Jump";
```

the type of the expression `"Jump"` is converted from "5-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  And you're trying to assign that *pointer* value to an *array* object, which a) isn't a pointer, and b) cannot be assigned to anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Use `strcpy` from `<string.h>`-

```
 strcpy(word,"Jump");
```

And similar for rest of them.

You just can't do `word ="Jump"`. As the contents are modifiable, the *arrays* themselves are not.